# how to import excel sheet name as date in a column using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, datetime

I have a large excel data which its sheet name is a date of a whole year. I want to import the sheet name in order to put it as a date column. How can I make it by using python?

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd


xls = xlrd.open_workbook(r'<path_to_your_excel_file>', on_demand=True)
pd.to_datetime(xls.sheet_names())
```